# In Verilog, Explain me this line of code

Tags: verilog

Please explain me what this line of code does

> assign m_ext[0] = { {5{m[0][15]}} , m[0] };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The m[0][15] means the 15th element of array element m[0]. the 5{} means 5 copies of m[0][15] and finally {} is concatenation only so you should have

```
m_ext[0] = {m[0][15], m[0][15], m[0][15], m[0][15], m[0][15], m[0]}
```

Basically I think you are extending the 15th bit of element m[0] 5 times

Comment: Without more context, its impossible to say, but it looks very much like a sign extension from a 16-bit value (`m[0]`) to an 21-bit value (`m_ext[0]`) of which there are a bunch as `m` and `m_ext` are indexed and probably arrays.

Comment: @Unn that's what I was thinking too but I didn't want to confuse him in case I was wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

{a,b}  represent concatenation of two values
and a[][] it is multidimensional array
and array is stored accordingly row wise fashion